# jQuery - auto input focus when scroll hit certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery plugin called [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/)
to work with scroll action.

What I want to achieve is setting focus on the first input element of a section that is in the viewport and move the focus to the input of next respective sections when scrolled down. And, when scroll back to the first section up above, it should set the focus back to the input of the first section.

The following is what I have on my actual working setup that is using the aforementioned plugin.
Unfortunately, I can't really get the plugin up and running in my [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/vy8hm/).

This code block works in terms of setting focus on page load and changing focus to the targeted input when scrolled down
but scrolling back to the top section does not set the focus back.

```
(function($) {

var firstInput = $('section').find('input[type=text]').filter(':visible:first');

if (firstInput != null) {
    firstInput.focus();
}

$('section').waypoint(function () {
    var getFocus = $(this).find('input[type=text]').filter(':visible:first');
    getFocus.focus();
});

$('section').waypoint(function () {
    var getFocus = $(this).find('input[type=text]').filter(':visible:first');
    getFocus.focus();
}, {
    offset: function () {
        return -$(this).height();
    }
});

});
```

Here is my [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/vy8hm/)
that doesn't have the plugin part.

As long as somebody can explain how they should be done in normal jQuery
if not familiar with this plugin.

Comment: Just add the plugin as external resource: http://jsfiddle.net/LX262/

Comment: @mplungjan Hi, is that a CDN for the plugin? I didn't know CDN was available for rather not major plugins.

Comment: No, that is the js file from the author's example page

Comment: And steel his bandwidth? Why don't you just copy the entire code and paste it in your fiddle for testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery Waypoints is very straightforward to use. I haven't tried with your code but I got it done with this:

```
$('input:first').focus();

$('section').waypoint(function() {
    $(this).find('input:first').focus();
});
```

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/vy8hm/1/).

However, using mousewheel on scrolling down, the scroll sometimes jumps back at the mid part. It might be how the browser reacts on input focus. I haven't gone through the whole documentation but there is no example for input focus.

---

If you're only looking to do just this simple task I suggest you drop the plugin. I can show you how to get this done with jQuery.

You can handle the scrolling with jQuery's `scroll()` function. You need to get the `scrollTop()` on scrolling event then compare it with the `<input>`'s top `offset()`.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
        var offset = $(this).offset();

        if(st >= offset.top -20 && st < offset.top + $(this).height()){
            $(this).focus();  
        } 
    });  
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/vy8hm/4/).

Comment: Yeah I had the same jumping issue on a fiddle. It works perfectly on my working setup now. The only added part is the use of `direction` on a chained waypoint function to which I gave different offset value when scroll up and down. Without this, the very top section won't hit the target when scroll back up. I will also give the normal jquery approach a try. Thanks for your thorough input.